# Log user information on failed attempt

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to be able to access my user details when login fail so that I can count the number of times of failed attempt a user has. How can i access the userdetails and save it to my database on failure? I read somewhere that AuthenticationFailureHandler might a be a solution to this but from what I see, it works only with formLogin?

I have a signin endpoint

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ApiOperation(value = "Sign in endpoint", notes = "You have to provide a valid login request")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@ApiParam(value = "The login request", required = true)
                                          @Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    // Set authentication so that when /authenticate, we can retrieve the authenticated user

   . . .
```

This is my authentrypointjwt when authenticate fails.

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("> AuthEntryPointJwt");
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

This is my websecurity

```
   @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

        @Autowired
        UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

        @Bean
        public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
            LOGGER.info("> AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationJwtTokenFilter");
            return new AuthTokenFilter();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
            LOGGER.info("> AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder");
            authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            LOGGER.info("> AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBean");
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/test/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/signup").hasAuthority("SUPER_ADMIN");

            http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD",
                    "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
            configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
            final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `AuthenticationFailureHandler` will only be called if you customise the filter for authentication by extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` like what formLogin does.

But it seems that you are now implementing a customised authentication way using `spring-mvc-rest` , and you can do the following which equivalents to what `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` does to invoke `AuthenticationFailureHandler` :

```java
@RestController
public void AuthenticateController {

    @Autowired AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
        }catch (AuthenticationException failed) {
          failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, failed);
        }
    }
}
```

*P.S. As you are customising authentication using spring-mvc-rest rather than following the spring security infrastructure to implement it based on the Servlet Filter , I assume that you also need to configure spring security to totally ignore `AuthenticateController` and no other spring security feature will be applied to it . I normally will follow the spring security infrastructure which customize the authentication process based on Servlet Filter as it is more compatible with the spring security ecosystem.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have decided to use a customized Authentication Provider where I handle my own "authenticate" function. this way, i can provide own way of  authentication & also access the user information.